# geometry: Calculate the fillable vertical space for a tcolorbox of vertical leaders

Tags: tcolorbox, geometry, leaders

For the last page, a new sentence is typed above the footer that resulted in overlapping with the `tcolorbox`.

Therefore, I would like to make `tcolorbox` calculate the fillable vertical space of the last page without overlapping the new sentence `End of the Exam`.

However, I don't want to change the footer geometry in order to keep the same layout of the first page.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize = 14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[
includefoot,
foot = 0 mm,
bottom = 20 mm
]{geometry}


\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newcommand{\myfooter}{
    \iflastpage{\raisebox{5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\large End of the Exam}}{}%
    \hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    Instructors%
}

\firstpagefooter{}{\myfooter}{}
\runningfooter{}{\myfooter}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \begin{fillAnswerRules}
        \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
        \leaders \hbox:n
        {
            \makebox[\textwidth][s]
            {
                \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
                \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
            }
        }\vfill
        \null
    \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \FillAnswerRules
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \FillAnswerRules
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\enlargethispage{-1cm}` or something similar in order to make it so that the `tcolorbox` environment using `/tcb/height fill` sees a shorter last page:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize = 14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[xparse,breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[includefoot,foot=0mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newcommand{\myfooter}{%
    \iflastpage{\raisebox{5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\large End of the Exam}}{}%
    \hrule\vspace{5pt}%
    Instructors%
}

\firstpagefooter{}{\myfooter}{}
\runningfooter{}{\myfooter}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \begin{fillAnswerRules}
        \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
        \leaders \hbox:n
        {
            \makebox[\textwidth][s]
            {
                \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
                \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
            }
        }\vfill
        \null
    \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \FillAnswerRules
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]%
    \enlargethispage{-1cm}%
    \FillAnswerRules
\end{document}
```

[image]

For fun, after the discussion in comments:

```latex
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[fontsize = 14pt]{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[breakable, skins, xparse]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage[includefoot,foot=2mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}

\newcommand{\myfooter}{%
  \iflastpage{\raisebox{5pt}[0pt][0pt]{\large End of the Exam}}{}%
    \par
    \vspace*{5pt}%
    Instructors%
}

\firstpagefooter{}{\myfooter}{}
\runningfooter{}{\myfooter}{}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { diaa / answers }
{
    d .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_distance_dim,
    t .dim_set:N = \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim,
    c .tl_set:N  = \l__diaa_answers_color_tl,
    d .initial:n = 10mm,
    t .initial:n = 0.2pt,
    c .initial:n = gray,
}

\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    enhanced, height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt,
    overlay={
      \draw[red, decorate, decoration=snake] ([yshift=-4pt]frame.south~west) --
                 ([yshift=-4pt]frame.south~east);}, #1
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\FillAnswerRules}{O{}}
{
    \begin{fillAnswerRules}
        \keys_set:nn { diaa / answers } { #1 }
        \leaders \hbox:n
        {
            \makebox[\textwidth][s]
            {
                \color{\l__diaa_answers_color_tl}
                \vrule width 0pt height 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                depth 0.5\l__diaa_answers_distance_dim
                \leaders \hrule height \l__diaa_answers_thickness_dim \hfill
            }
        }\vfill
        \null
    \end{fillAnswerRules}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \FillAnswerRules
    \newpage
    \lipsum[1-2]%
    \enlargethispage{-1cm}%
    \FillAnswerRules
\end{document}
```

[image: snaky footer]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Out of curiosity: on the first page, why is there a small gap between the box frame and the `\hrule` of the footer? and how to control it?

Comment: The `\hrule` comes from your `\myfooter` command. It doesn't belong to the page body, so there is no reason why it should coincide with the bottom of the page body. If you don't want to see it, just comment it out.

Comment: I need to have a horizontal rule as a ceiling of my footer. So, could you suggest another approach of drawing the rule while controlling the spacing between it and the bottom of the box? For instance, I need to manually set the spacing between the rule and the box.

Comment: If it really is the bottom of the box that matters, using an `overlay` in the `tcolorbox` would be the thing. But since the bottom of the box is as low as possible in the page body... try something like `\vspace*{-4pt}%` (or `-2pt`, etc. if you want to see the rule) at the beginning of `\myfooter`, isn't it sufficient? I don't quite understand what you want, because the above screenshot does show a “ceiling” `\hrule` for both footers.

Comment: Setting the option of `overlay` of the `tcolorbox` doesn't change the output unless I am doing it wrong. On the other side, you are right, the spacing between the `hrule` and the box bottom is `4pt`. Since I am a question machine `XD`, where does `4pt` come from?

Comment: The `4pt` comes from just trying it. Properly computing it would probably involve `\baselineskip`. For the overlay, try: `\usepackage[breakable,skins,xparse]{tcolorbox}` ... `\NewTColorBox { fillAnswerRules } { O{} }
{
    enhanced, height~fill, text~fill, colback=white, boxrule=2pt, sharp~corners,
    boxsep=0pt, left=10pt, right=10pt, top=8pt, bottom=0pt,
    overlay={
      \draw[red] ([yshift=-1pt]frame.south~west) --
                 ([yshift=-1pt]frame.south~east);}, #1
}` and you'll see a red horizontal rule just `1pt` below the bottom of the box.

Comment: I really appreciate your patience `:)`. Thank you!

Comment: I added an example with `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}` and `\draw[red, decorate, decoration=snake]` for fun (and to show how `tcolorbox` and `tikz` are powerful), see the updated answer. :-)

Comment: I see you are a man of culture as well `:)`.